# routing doesn't work in angularJS and throws exception of [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#banana">Banana</a>
<a href="#tomato">Tomato</a>

<p>Click on the links to change the content.</p>

<p>The HTML shown in the ng-view directive are written in the template property of the $routeProvider.when method.</p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
    })
    .when("/banana", {
        template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a following code which is implementing a very simple routing example. But unfortunately It doesnot work and there is an error of [$injector:modulerr] in angular.min.js (38,282).

Comment: It works [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/t2X8892wS74udPigLfkK?p=preview).

Comment: yes it is but why it throws an exception when I ran it in my pc. what wll be the reasons? I tried this code on IE windows 10 and opera. I will get same results from both browsers.